# Electron Desktop App with Authentication and backend

Tags: electron, aws-amplify, desktop

I am building a desktop application in electron. For authentication I have tried AWS Amplify but it is having issues working. I was thinking of using a different authenticator and backend. I am wondering if anyone has any reccomendations for authentication and backend for an electron app.

I have tried AWS amplify, looks like it is more for web apps and mobile.